# Angular 4 execute function from another component

Tags: angular

I'm build a webapp using Angular4 and I'm trying to create a button to call functions on other components.

I was reading other similar questions here, but they have a scenario where the components are child or sibling components with the declaration on the html, e.g.:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <sibling-component></sibling-component>
</parent-component>
```

However, I'm working on a different scenario, because my components are Invoked via `routing` and I can't make it work.

Basically I have a `header` on the page with some controls to execute functions, but these functions need to trigger/change data on other components loaded via the routing.

For example, I have the routing `/store` to show a list of stores, I also have a drawer on this page that I want to show when the user clicks on a button on the **header**, this is the problem, because I can't propagate the event from the `HeaderComponent` to the `StoreComponent`.

These are my files:

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    templateUrl: `
        <section class="container">
            <button (click)="clickFilter()">Open filter</button>
        </section>
    `
})

export class HeaderComponent {
    @Output() onFilter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    clickFilter():void {
        this.onFilter.emit('Register click');
    }
}
```

**store.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'store.html'
})

export class StoreComponent {
    onFilterClick(event) {
        console.log('Fire onFilterClick: ', event);
    }
}

// store.html
<article class="card" (onFilter)="onFilterClick($event)">
    Test
</article>
```

But this is not working.

Also, I don't actually need to call a function, I could just pass a boolean value, for example, to bind to a property on the StoreComponent and then toggle the div inside the html file.

Comment: It's not totally clear how these components are arranged in the app. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help. The components that are not in parent-child relationship can communicate either through common parent or through a service on parent injector. If communicating through parent is not an option... do the math.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction service approach

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I didn't get time to test it but similar solution worked for me. the code created for your need.

Create a service like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private _listners = new Subject<any>();

    listen(): Observable<any> {
       return this._listners.asObservable();
    }

    filter(filterBy: string) {
       this._listners.next(filterBy);
    }

}
```

then implement in your header component like this

```
// header.component.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    templateUrl: `
        <section class="container">
            <button (click)="clickFilter()">Open filter</button>
        </section>
    `
 })

export class HeaderComponent {
     @Output() onFilter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

     constructor(private _messageService: MessageService){}
     clickFilter():void {
         // this.onFilter.emit('Register click');
         this._messageService.filter('Register click');
     }
 }
```

then use in your store component like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'store',
    template: `<article class="card">
                 Test
              </article>`
})

export class StoreComponent {
    constructor(private _messageService: MessageService){
        this._messageService.listen().subscribe((m:any) => {
            console.log(m);
            this.onFilterClick(m);
        })
    }

    onFilterClick(event) {
        console.log('Fire onFilterClick: ', event);
    }
 }
```

The concept is that you can use observable in a service and subscribe in the component where you want it (store.component) and can send event from anywhere in the app like i did in the header.component

I hope it will help you

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly. Also, I think this is even better to use a service because i can put all the shared functions in a single place instead of being all over the place.

Comment: little typo is there in StoreComponent (subscirbe -> subscribe), rest is working perfect for me. Thank you

Comment: What is the use of EventEmitter in header component?

Comment: see the clickFilter() in header component  the line to emit event is commented so you can remove the EventEmitter from header component. i wrote it show the solution for the question

Comment: how do i unsubscribe inside store.component?

Comment: Super Answer... Worked Prefectly.....

Answer (score 4):

I had a similiar situation, but didn´t want to make a service for this. I managed to pass it like callback. It would be something like this:

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'header',
templateUrl: `
    <section class="container">
        <button (click)="myFunction()">Open filter</button>
    </section>
`})
export class HeaderComponent {
   @Input() myFunction: Function;
}
```

Then just to call it passing the function and parameter

```
// store.html
<header [myFunction]="functionOnStore"></header>
```

And just declaring functionOnStore normally on store component

Comment: seems like this would pass a function into the component, not call it?

Comment: Yep. It will pass the function but also call/execute it. It's JS magic!!!