# angular 4 - update property in another component without parent child relationship

Tags: angular

I have 2 components which are unrelated, `navbar` and `edit-page`

In the `navbar` component I get a list of page titles from a collection, and I use the `edit-page` component to edit a page title, but since I can always see all the page titles from the `navbar` component, I want it to be updated as soon as I edit a page title.

How to achieve this without `@input` and `@output` ? As far as I understand I should creating some kind of a shared service but I am not sure how to go about it exactly?

**pages.service.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PagesService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getPages() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/pages')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getEditPage(id) {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/pages/edit-page/' + id)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    postEditPage(value) {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/pages/edit-page/' + value.id, value)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

**navbar component**

```
pages: any[];
ngOnInit() {
        this.pagesService.getPages().subscribe(pages => {
            this.pages = pages;
        });
    }
```

**edit-page component**

```
editPage({ value, valid }) {
        if (valid) {
            this.pagesService.postEditPage(value).subscribe(res => {
                if (res == "ok") {
                    this.successMsg = true;
                }

            });
        } else {
            console.log('Form is not valid');
        }
    }
```

So after the `editPage` method is executed in the `edit-page` component I would like the `pages` property in the `navbar` component to be updated automatically.

Comment: A component should listen an update event.

Comment: @RomanC Any further clues? I'm pretty new to angular.

Comment: can it be done without @input and @output?

Comment: they are essential if your parent component tells to a child what to do and a child should respond to the parent what has been done.

Comment: it will help check it [angular 4 execute function from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303683/angular-4-execute-function-from-another-component/45305052#45305052)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Observables like this.

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

export class MyService(){
public someProp  = new BehaviorSubject<string(null);

 }
 
 export class ComponentOne implements OnInit{
     constructor(private service:MyService){
    }
    ngOnInit(){
    //this will set the value of someProp
      this.service.someProp.next('some value')
    }
 
 }
 export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit{
    constructor(private service:MyService){
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        //this will get latest value from someProp
        // also will update when it changes
      this.service.someProp.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('this is the current value',res)
      })
    
    }
 
 }
```

Comment: I am using http.get to get the values from a database, can it be used with this approach? I have pasted my current pagesService.ts in my question.

Comment: Ye just add a BehaviorSubject like i showed you call it mode or editMode or w/e make sense to you. subscribe to it and it will change automatically.

Comment: ok kinda getting there. in my pages.service.ts i have this `public someProp  = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);` . I have kept the name `someProp` so it is easily spotted. Now i am SETTING it in navbar.component.ts inside nginit like so `this.pagesService.getPages().subscribe(pages => {
            this.pagesService.someProp.next(pages);
            this.pages = this.pagesService.someProp;
        });` That works because now to iterate thru it I have to use `pages.value` and not just `pages`, so so far so good. But how do I update it when I update the page title in another component?

Comment: You can see how I am doing the update in the `edit-page` component in my question.

Comment: you just call someProp.next() everytime you want to update it that's all if (res == "ok") {
                    this.successMsg = true;this.service.someProp.next('update...'). 
                }

Answer (score 0):

Create a service which returns pages and emit the event using **EventEmitter** when the pages array is changed. Inject **PagesService** to both of your **NavbarComponent** and **EditPageComponent**.

Make changes in EditPageComponent and update the pages in the PageService and emit the **pagesChanged** event. Then **subscribe** to pagesChanged event in your **NavbarComponent**.

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { pages} from './../shared/pages.model';


export class PageService {

    pagesChanged = new EventEmitter<Pages[]>();

    private pages: Page[] = [
        new Page('PageName1'),
        new Page('PageName2'),
      ];    

      getPages() {
          return this.pages.slice();
      }

      editPage(page: Page) {
        // write you logic to edit the page or pages array.
        // Emit the pagesChanged event.
        this.pagesChanged.emit(this.pages.slice());
      }
}
```

And Subscribe to pagesChanged event in the NavabarComponent like this.

```
import { Page} from './../shared/pages.model';
import { PagesService } from './pages.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  pages: Page[];

  constructor(private pageService: PagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pages= this.pageService.getPages();
    this.pageService.pagesChanged
      .subscribe(
        (pages: Page[]) => {
          this.pages= pages;
        } 
      )
  }

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't get it, you see how I am getting pages in the navbar, how do i move that to the service? I already tried moving it to the service before but could not.

Comment: I just added my pages.service.ts code so maybe that helps