# How to call function of component B from component A

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I think this may be a duplicate question.

I have a component B in which there is a function `saveContact()`. I want to call this function from another function of component A .

So I

1. Imported component B in component A. Then created a viewChild
2. `@ViewChild(ContactformComponent) contactForm: ContactformComponent;`
3. Called the function

   `saveContactForm() {
    this.contactForm.saveContact();
    }`

When I run the application I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveContact' of undefined`.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Parent Component

```
import { ContactformComponent } from './forms/contactform/contactform.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-insert',
templateUrl: './insert.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./insert.component.scss'],
animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class InsertComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(ContactformComponent) contactForm;

saveContactForm() {
this.contactForm.saveContact();
}
}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-contactform',
templateUrl: './contactform.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contactform.component.scss']
})
export class ContactformComponent implements OnInit {
contactForm: FormGroup;

... // Form Code

  public saveContact() {
  const savedContact = {
  contactType: this.contactType,
  contactDescription: this.contactTypeDescription,
  contactSubType: this.contactSubType,
  contactSubTypeDescription: this.contactSubTypeDescription,
  referenceNumber: this.referenceNumber,
  lastVerifiedDate: this.parseDate(this.contactlastVerifiedDate.toString()),
  startDate: this.parseDate(this.contactStartDate.toString()),
  endDate: this.parseDate(this.contactEndDate.toString())
  };
  this.savedContact.emit(savedContact);
  this.snackbar.open('Contact Saved,Click on Create Customer or Fill more 
  Details', 'Close', {
  duration: 5000
  });
  }
```

Comment: The correct syntax is to use `@ViewChild('template-variable') contactForm: ContactformComponent;` where you need to use `template-variable` in your component HTML like this <div #template-variable></div>

Comment: It will be better if you use services, because you create a service and that you can use everywhere.

Comment: Is B a child of A ?

Comment: Using a service is also better if you want to call the function in multiple component, create a singleton instance and inject it in component.

Comment: @Niladri Currently I am doing it the way it is mentioned in the approved answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303683/angular-4-execute-function-from-another-component

Comment: @Ahmed, If B is not child of A, how do you use B in A?

Comment: @Ahmed I was talking about the same to use a service

Comment: Extremely sorry .. Yes B is child component of A

Comment: Do you really expect us to debug code we cannot see?

Comment: @TheHeadRush There is no logical code except the one I have written in question.If you want me to paste the form code I will do that too .. but it doesn't help anyone

Comment: Ultimately, `this.contactForm` is undefined. Could be several reasons for that. 1) Is it actually in the template? 2) Are you sure you're importing the right `ContactformComponent`?

Comment: Yes I am importing the Contact FormComponent

Comment: @ahmed - turn your component into a service. You're getting undefined because your component isn't initialized anywhere. To initialize it you would need to define it in the template somewhere. BUT please use a service like you suggest in the answer you are trying to copy.

Comment: share your component htmls as well

Answer (score 0):

Is the method public in the child component:

```
public saveContact() {
    //saveContact
 }
```

in the parent class...

```
export class A {
@ViewChild(ContactformComponent) contactForm: ContactformComponent;
```

Comment: Yes I tried making the method public but still same issue

Comment: do you have the child component declared in the app.module ?

Comment: Yes I have declared

Comment: What does your parent component template look like?

Comment: what about insert.component.html

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, include child component in parent component.html

1. Import ViewChild in your parent.component.ts

   `import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";`
2. Import Child Component in parent.component.ts and include child component in parent.component.html

**parent.component.ts**

`import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ChildComponent } from "./child.component";`

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) contactForm;
  saveContactForm() {
    console.log(this);
    setTimeout(() => this.contactForm.saveContact(), 0);
  }
}

**parent.component.html**

```
<child></child>
<button (click)="saveContactForm()">Save</button>
```

On removing above mentioned child component from parent.component.html , it will throw below error in developer tools

**sandbox.517cc37e.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveContact' of undefined**

working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/rlq4xj5q0n